# How to know the coordinate of a dot in point cloud in phyton?

Tags: coordinates, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, open3d

I have a set of geo-referenced point cloud. I want to know the location of one or many points coordinate. How can I find this?
As a comparison, in cloudcompare, we can check the coordinate of a point by using pointpicking tool. Any help on this issue is highly appreciated. Thank you.

I expect to get result like in the cloud compare which can show me the x, y, and z of the dot either in local or global coordinate

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is too broad, I assume a few things.

If you use open3d, you can load your point cloud. PointCLoud class has `points` property which gives you the coordinates of the points. It returns,

```
# float64 array of shape (num_points, 3), use numpy.asarray() to access data
```

###### A simple example to get coordinates

```
print("Load a ply point cloud, print it, and render it")
ply_point_cloud = o3d.data.PLYPointCloud()
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(ply_point_cloud.path)
pcd.points
```